# Why do I keep getting this error message after updating to OS X 10.8.1?

Tags: macos, command-line

After I updated to OS X 10.8.1, I keep getting this error message when I execute `purge`:

> [ERROR]    The device-file for this operating system, 'osx-12.1.0.xml', was not found. An attempt to revert to a previous revision of the OS device-file: 'osx-12.0.0.xml' has been made. Please file a Radar report with Apple, on the 'CoreProfile' component, version 'X'.

Is there anything I need to do to fix the error? To what exactly is the error message referring?

Comment: That’s probably a message a developer forgot to delete, as only Apple developers can file radar reports.

Comment: That would be an answer. If then you would have a link to a page where they say just Apple developers can file radar reports, that would be perfect.

Comment: It’s not explicitly written anywhere that only developers can file radar reports, but when a non-developer tries to login at radar.apple.com, they are presented with an error message saying so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `purge` command is still executing correctly, but it looks like Apple forgot to update the file and it's kicking this error back.

The best temporary solution is the following:

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreProfile.framework/Versions/A/Resources/De vices/`
3. `sudo ln -s osx-12.0.0.xml osx-12.1.0.xml`

This will add a non destructive symbolic link that is a reference to another file; in this case you're pointing the link 12.1.0 to the previous file, 12.0.0. Since this is only a link, if an update does roll out with this file it will just overwrite the link.

This is the best temp fix, and I'm sure it's been submitted a few times to their bug tracker. Hopefully it gets fixed soon! There is an Apple support communities thread about the same thing [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4234751).

Answer (score 1):

That’s probably a message a developer forgot to delete, as only registered Apple developers can file radar reports. Usually, these messages are present only in the developer betas.

Source: http://radar.apple.com

Comment: Err, anybody can register as an OS X developer and create radars. At least it worked for me a few weeks ago.

Comment: Yep. But you have to register, that’s the point.
EDIT: Wait, are you thinking that by Apple developers I mean Apple’s own in-house developers? I mean those who register as developers with Apple.

Comment: Please edit your answer then